# Getting Error on PHP OOP Database Class __construct()

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am trying to set up a basic database class using OOP in PHP and Mysqli and here is the code I have

```
class AppDB {
    private $host     = "localhost";
    private $user     = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $db       = "test";
    protected $_mysql;


  public function __construct(){
       $this->_mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
          if ($this->_mysql->connect_error){
             die($this->_mysql->connect_error);
          }
   }

}
```

but I am getting following errors

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: what is the line 31?

Comment: This actually in inle 31 `$this->_mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code with below code

```
public function __construct(){
       $this->_mysql = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);
          if ($this->_mysql->connect_error){
             die($this->_mysql->connect_error);
          }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Harsh Chunara but can you please let me know why we should use the `$this->` coding here?

Comment: Reason behind that it is OOP way, that variable in class to be used with $this-> in any function of that class

And out of class with class object